# How to add php string that get category title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just wanted to know how to apply php string when you want to get the title:
ex.

```
 <h1 class="page-title"><?php single_cat_title(__('category:','themename')); ?></h1>
```

so if the title is "Video's", the button in the content will change to "Watch now" instead of "Read more" which is the default.

something like

```
if title is = "video's" {
echo "<button>Watch now</button>"
}<button>Readmore</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `false` as second parameter to just return the value (not print). And then just compare it.

```
if (single_cat_title("", false) == "video's") {
    echo "Watch now";
} else {
    echo "Read more";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, its works but the only problem is i cant use quotation marks in "video's" instead I use "videos".

Comment: That's odd. It should work. But glad you got it working. There is different quotation marks too. Maybe if you copy-paste it from web to your code.

Answer (score 0):

### *Simple PHP if/else*

Here's the code which will work for you

```
if (single_cat_title("",false) == "video's") {
 echo "<button>Watch now</button>"
} else {
 echo "<button>Readmore</button>"
}
```

I am just assuming that title is actually titled video

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic approach you can check video post by it's category id even with the category name. here is the example code.

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');
if( $category_id == 'your cat id'){
echo 'watch video';
{
else{
echo 'readmore';
}
```

Hope it helps.  cheers!